# moving UILabel upside with NSTimer

Tags: iphone

HI all,
i want to move a UILabel up for 5 sec and gets hidden.
Something we see in games, when we get bouus or something,
a text comes up  ,moves up saying something "+300" etc.

How to do move UIlabel?
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [UIView animation methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW62)

i.e.

```
- (void)showScoreLabelFor:(int)score {
    // Make a label
    UILabel *scoreLabel = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)] autorelease];

    // Set it's text to the score we want to show
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%+i", score]];

    // Center it in the view
    [scoreLabel sizeToFit];
    [scoreLabel setCenter:CGPointMake([[self view] center].x, 200)];

    // Add it to the view
    [[self view] addSubview:scoreLabel];

    // Animate it up 100 pixels ver 2 seconds
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    CGRect frame = [scoreLabel frame];
    frame.origin.y -= 100;
    [scoreLabel setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Anything between __beginAnimations__ and __commitAnimations__ is animated - so if I set the y position of the label to be 100 higher it will slide the label up 100px. If you edit your question and add the code you're having trouble with I can have a look.

Comment: i just need to display a text saying  "+ 500"

which show move in up direction and after 3-4 seconds, it should gets hides.

thanks man i really appreciate ur help

Comment: I've edited my question to make it into a method that put s a label onto your viewcontrollers view and animates it up by 100px over 2 seconds. Use it like __[self showScoreLabelFor:200];__

Comment: That what i was looking for man

thanks a ton for ur code snippet.
its working.....yippy